# How to convert []interface to []struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, slice

For example, this code:

```
type person struct { //struct
  id   int
  name string
}

func example()  {
  var (
      p []person
      pi []interface{}
  )
  pi = append(pi, person{
      id:   1,
      name: "Mike",
  })
}
```

How to convert `pi` to `p`?

Comment: for k, v := range pi {
  p[k] = v //Cannot use 'v' (type interface{}) as type person in assignment 
}

Comment: i can use Type assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type person struct { //struct
    id   int
    name string
}

func main() {
    var (
        p  []person
        pi []interface{}
    )
    pi = append(pi, person{
        id:   1,
        name: "Mike",
    })
    for _, tmp := range pi {
         // fmt.Println(tmp,k)
         p = append(p, tmp.(person))
         fmt.Println( p)
    }

}
```